# Best solution for downloading and caching images

Tags: android, image, caching

i've got a question about best solution for caching downloaded images. From internet are downloaded URLs of images i want to show with specifig tag. On some other activities will be showed previews of images and after click on preview will be shown image in full size and his description. My idea is save info about image to database with path to directory named after tag in cache directory. When preview should be shown, i look to cache and if there image is, good and if not image will be downloaded

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a naming convention so you won't need to use the database ?

Like this :
Profil picture for user 1 will be in
tmp/mypackage/pic_cache/user_pic_1.jpg